# PHP Crypt encrypt/decrypt not returning the same hash tag

Tags: php, crypt

Sign up form - Password is 123456:

```
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
$salt = '$2a$10$R.Baj0mvj5doNvtvzDjwP5$';
$password = crypt("$pwd", $salt);
```

Hash in the database:

$2a$10$R.Baj0mvj5doNvtvzDjwPuN/W8Z3n6RVGyM0pM

Hash comparison when user is login in - Password again, 123456:

```
$salt = '$2a$10$R.Baj0mvj5doNvtvzDjwP5$';
$crypt_pass=crypt($password,$salt);
```

The $crypt_pass = $2a$10$R.Baj0mvj5doNvtvzDjwPuN/W8Z3n6RVGyM0pMQB89k2m9nYRIN6O
The password hash in the database is: $2a$10$R.Baj0mvj5doNvtvzDjwPuN/W8Z3n6RVGyM0pM

Why aren't they matching when I'm hashing them with the same salt?

Comment: Most likely, the passwords are not *exactly* the same.

Comment: But the sign up page uses 123456, then they try to log in using 123456, and the hash is different? How does Crypt work if this is the case? Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Blowfish as your hash type. That will always return different values for the same string and salt. If you want your hashes to match use SHA 512.

```
$salt = '$6$rounds=5000$usesomesillystringforsalt$';
```